# Why does this program stop running after two guesses?

Tags: c#, loops, response

I am creating a simple C# console application game that creates a random number, then displays either "too high", "too low" or "correct", it is then supposed to ask the user to input another number & then tell them whether that number is "too high", "too low" or "correct", once the right number is guessed, it should say "correct" and then display the number of guesses it took to get the correct number (this part I'm not sure how to do). Besides that I've created the code & it will tell you whether your guess is too high or too low, and once you try to enter a second guess it automatically says it's correct. How can I get the program to read more guesses, and how do I display the number of guesses?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _5.Number_Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double response, guess;  
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 101);
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess for a random number between 1 & 100");
            guess = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (guess > randomNumber)
                Console.WriteLine("Too high");

            if (guess < randomNumber)
                Console.WriteLine("Too low");

            if (guess == randomNumber)
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");

             Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");

             response = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        while (response <= 1 && response >=100);
        Console.WriteLine("Correct, Goodbye!");
        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Spencerstead, learn to use the debugger to step through your code..

Comment: you should use int instead of double.

Answer (score 0):

Your "while" condition isn't right, it currently checks if the number is within the 1-100 range while it should check if it was the right number.

I would change it to:

```
while(guess != randomNumber);
```

or break when it is on the correct value:

```
if (guess == randomNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
    break;
}
```

I would also note that your "response" value is currently useless once you fix your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need your guess as a double as the random number will only generate an integer. Also the responce variable is also not needed, as the loop can just be looped until:

```
while(guess != randomNumber);
```

Like the above answer said. If you would like to add a count of how many guesses the user takes to guess the number, add a count variable before the the opening 'do' loop.

```
int count = 0;
do
{
```

And in each guess where the user doesn't guess it correctly increment the count by one, just like this:

```
if (guess > randomNumber)
{
Console.WriteLine("Too high");
count += 1;
}

if (guess < randomNumber)
{
Console.WriteLine("Too low");
count += 1;
}
```

Then at the end when user guesses correctly

```
if (guess == randomNumber)
{
 Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
 Console.WriteLine("You took " + count + "guesses, to guess that number.");
}
```